# HTML5 audio player not autoplaying in ios safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

this audio is not getting autoplayed in IOS browsers. Even tried simulation of click. Still it's not working.

I'm using angular 7.

Comment: Read the new policies for autoplay in safari and mobile browser [HERE](https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/)

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, ogg format is not supported in Safari. See https://caniuse.com/#search=ogg

You could use an alternate format for your source audio, e.g. mp3 or wav.

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```